# Cannot find why Stack Overflow error appears

Tags: stack-overflow, julia

I am trying to make an [octree for randomly distributed set of particles](http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut). I have been trying to find where Stack Overflow Error appears whole day, but it was in vain. Could you please help me? The problem should be somewhere in (c == [0]) && (a > 0) part, however, I have no idea where. Thank you in advance!

```
type particle
  R::Vector{Float64}          # coordinates of the particle
  m::Float64                  # mass of the particle
  a_tree::Float64             # acceleration of particle calculated from tree
  a_exact::Float64            # acceleration of particle calculated by exact summation
end

type node
  parent::Int64               # node's parent number
  children::Vector{Int64}     # set of childrens' numbers
  l::Float64                  # size of the node
  R::Vector{Float64}          # radius of geometric center
  m::Float64                  # total mass of the node
  ptcl::Int64                 # pointer to the particle in it
end

function problem3_2(N::Int64)
particles = Vector{particle}(N)                 # Basically, our system
tree = Vector{node}(1)                          # Initial tree (root)
tree[1] = node(0,[0],1.0,[0.0,0.0,0.0],0.0,0)

for i in eachindex(particles)
  particles[i] = particle([rand() - 1/2, rand() - 1/2, rand() - 1/2], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  tree = InsertParticle(i,1,tree,particles)
end

return tree
end

function InsertParticle(i::Int64,k::Int64,tree,particles)
  c = tree[k].children
  a = tree[k].ptcl
  if (c == [0]) && (a == 0)
    tree[k].ptcl = i
  elseif (c == [0]) && (a > 0)
    j_1 = length(tree) + DetermOctant(particles[tree[k].ptcl],tree[k])
    j_2 = length(tree) + DetermOctant(particles[i],tree[k])
    tree[k].children = [x for x in length(tree)+1:length(tree)+8]
      for p = 1:8
        push!(tree,node(k,[0],tree[k].l/2,[0.0,0.0,0.0],0.0,0))
        if (p == 1) || (p == 4) || (p == 5) || (p == 8)
          tree[k+p].R[1] = tree[k].R[1] + tree[k+p].l/2
        else
          tree[k+p].R[1] = tree[k].R[1] - tree[k+p].l/2
        end
        if (p == 1) || (p == 2) || (p == 5) || (p == 6)
          tree[k+p].R[2] = tree[k].R[2] + tree[k+p].l/2
        else
          tree[k+p].R[2] = tree[k].R[2] - tree[k+p].l/2
        end
        if (p == 1) || (p == 2) || (p == 3) || (p == 4)
          tree[k+p].R[3] = tree[k].R[3] + tree[k+p].l/2
        else
          tree[k+p].R[3] = tree[k].R[3] - tree[k+p].l/2
        end

        end

    InsertParticle(tree[k].ptcl,j_1,tree,particles)
    InsertParticle(i,j_2,tree,particles)
    tree[k].ptcl = 0
  elseif (c != [0])
      j = DetermOctant(particles[i],tree[k])
      InsertParticle(i,tree[k].children[j],tree,particles)
  end
return tree
end


function DetermOctant(x::particle,y::node)
  c1 = y.R[1]; c2 = y.R[2]; c3 = y.R[3]
  x1 = sign(x.R[1] - c1); x2 = sign(x.R[2] - c2); x3 = sign(x.R[3] - c3)
  if (x1 > 0) && (x2 > 0) && (x3 > 0)
    n = 1
  elseif (x1 < 0) && (x2 > 0) && (x3 > 0)
    n = 2
  elseif (x1 < 0) && (x2 < 0) && (x3 > 0)
    n = 3
  elseif (x1 > 0) && (x2 < 0) && (x3 > 0)
    n = 4
  elseif (x1 > 0) && (x2 > 0) && (x3 < 0)
    n = 5
  elseif (x1 < 0) && (x2 > 0) && (x3 < 0)
    n = 6
  elseif (x1 < 0) && (x2 < 0) && (x3 < 0)
    n = 7
  else
    n = 8
  end
return n
end
```

Basically, I do know that the error should be somewhere here:

```
function InsertParticle(i::Int64,k::Int64,tree,particles)
  c = tree[k].children
  a = tree[k].ptcl
  if (c == [0]) && (a == 0)
    tree[k].ptcl = i
  elseif (c == [0]) && (a > 0)
    j_1 = length(tree) + DetermOctant(particles[tree[k].ptcl],tree[k])
    j_2 = length(tree) + DetermOctant(particles[i],tree[k])
    tree[k].children = [x for x in length(tree)+1:length(tree)+8]
      for p = 1:8
        push!(tree,node(k,[0],tree[k].l/2,[0.0,0.0,0.0],0.0,0))
        if (p == 1) || (p == 4) || (p == 5) || (p == 8)
          tree[k+p].R[1] = tree[k].R[1] + tree[k+p].l/2
        else
          tree[k+p].R[1] = tree[k].R[1] - tree[k+p].l/2
        end
        if (p == 1) || (p == 2) || (p == 5) || (p == 6)
          tree[k+p].R[2] = tree[k].R[2] + tree[k+p].l/2
        else
          tree[k+p].R[2] = tree[k].R[2] - tree[k+p].l/2
        end
        if (p == 1) || (p == 2) || (p == 3) || (p == 4)
          tree[k+p].R[3] = tree[k].R[3] + tree[k+p].l/2
        else
          tree[k+p].R[3] = tree[k].R[3] - tree[k+p].l/2
        end

        end

    InsertParticle(tree[k].ptcl,j_1,tree,particles)
    InsertParticle(i,j_2,tree,particles)
    tree[k].ptcl = 0
  elseif (c != [0])
      j = DetermOctant(particles[i],tree[k])
      InsertParticle(i,tree[k].children[j],tree,particles)
  end
return tree
end
```

However, I cannot see where the infinite loop appears. Sorry for bringing these all here in a such form, I just want to avoid XY-problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is probably a better question for CodeReview. StackOverflow is for short questions and explanations about programming, and not debugging scripts. CodeReview is as the name says: for reviewing code and analyzing larger scripts to learn/teach. This would be suitable to SO if you found a minimal example for what caused this, and asked why this behavior occurs.

Comment: In the line `tree[k+p].R[1] = tree[k].R[1] + tree[k+p].l/2`, the target index `k+p` should be `end` (the just inserted node). The same for the rest of these lines.